# html inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, action

How to input the parameter to action tag using a variable?
Example:

```
var actionurl="some url"
windowhandle.document.write('<form name=sample action=actionurl method="post" </form>');
windowhandle.document.sample.submit();
```

This is not working. I am getting 404 Page not found error. Please give me an alternate method

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting the value of `actionurl` in your form. Try this:

```
windowhandle.document.write('<form name=sample action=' + actionurl + 'method="post"> </form>');
```

**Edit:** You are also missing a ">" which I have now added.

Comment: Don't forget the > after "post", like so: '<form name=sample action=' + actionurl + 'method="post"></form>'

Comment: @onitake - yes well spotted, I have amended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var actionurl="some url"
windowhandle.document.write('<form name=sample action='+ actionurl +' method="post" </form>');
windowhandle.document.sample.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's `.format()` function:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var str = this;
    var i = 0;
    var len = arguments.length;
    var matches = str.match(/{}/g);
    if( !matches || matches.length !== len ) {
        throw "wrong number of arguments";
    }
    while( i < len ) {
        str = str.replace(/{}/, arguments[i] );
        i++;
    }
    return str;
};
```

Just paste that code into your script and it'll let you use the function.

Python's `.format()` is useful for clean string manipulations:

```
'I {} a {}'.format('am', 'string')
// I am a string
```

It just replaces the bracketed substrings with the parameters of the function.

Now, your new code would be like this:

```
var actionurl="some url"
windowhandle.document.write('<form name="sample" action="{}" method="post"></form>'.format(actionurl));
windowhandle.document.sample.submit();
```

Be sure to use quotes around the attributes!

Comment: I know. It's a JavaScript implementation of `.format()` from Python. I though that the OP wanted a way to insert strings into others without using plus signs.